# How to do a long left click on a W8 touch screen?

Tags: windows-8, touchscreen, mouse-click

An Windows application I use requires a long left click on a button.

I didn't manage to do it on a Windows 8 tablet. On Windows 8, a long touch leads to a right click.

Is there a way to change this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

A long click is a right click, it's the same on all Windows 7/8/8.1 Tablets. Holding your finger in the same place for 2 seconds produces a small white box around the finger, this represents a right click.

I'm sorry, I don't think I understand what you're actually asking.

Comment: My question is: `Is there a way to change this behavior?`. Does a Windows parameter (GPO, register...) exist to disable this feature (transforming a long click into a right click)? Or how could I go around and provide a long click to my application? Is my request clearer?

Comment: Oh I see what you mean; you are trying to perform a click and hold using the left mouse button, instead you're getting a right click because you're using touch instead of a mouse...

Comment: Yes you've got it. Any idea?

Comment: I had a think about it and to be honest it's not something I've done or ever had to have done. It's a very strange design concept to have a user click and hold a button in any software. It's not even something you could do on a standard keyboard, it's only something you could do with a physical mouse... I know you can click and drag using touch which is a similar action; but probably not what you're after.

Comment: Well thanks for the reply anyway. If anybody else has an idea, I would be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

As of right now, there is no way to change it to a left click, but I have found that making the right click as slow as possible in the pen and touch settings under *Control Panel -> all control panel settings -> pen and touch* works fine. Change your double click so that the speed is slow but the tolerance is high and I have found that to work ok, not perfect at all, but OK. If you are able to disable right click touch then that should work even better.